Flux operator and phase operator in Cooper pair box
An isolated Cooper pair box is equivalent to a capacitor in parallel with a non-linear inductance and its hamiltonian is equal to
$$H = 4E_C \hat{n}^2 -E_J \cos{\hat\varphi}$$
In particular, $E_C = \frac{e^2}{2C_J}$, where $C_J$ is the capacitance of the system.
Using Heisenberg's equation of motion and the commutation relation between $\hat n$ and $\hat{\varphi}$, we find the second Josephson relation, i.e.
$$\hbar \dot{\hat \varphi} = 2e \hat V$$
where
$$\hat V = \frac{-2e \hat n}{C_J}$$
Now, we tipically use the second Josephson relation to determine the relationship between the phase $\hat \varphi$ and the branch flux $\hat{\Phi}$, defined as
$$\hat{\Phi} = \int_{0}^{t} dt' \, \hat V(t')$$
It is tipically stated that, from the second Josephson relation, we can find that
$$\hat{\Phi} = \frac{\hbar \hat \varphi}{2e}$$
However, I do not understand why.
Indeed, integrating the second Josephson relation from $t=0$ until the generic instant of time $t$, I find that
$$\hat{\varphi}(t)-\hat{\varphi}(0)=\frac{2e}{\hbar} \hat{\Phi}$$
It is equivalent to the previous one if we set $\hat{\varphi}(0)=0$. Can we neglect this operator? Why is it never reported?
